# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.Context.addLifecycleListener

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, nosuchmethoderror

I am trying to setup my java workspace with eclipse and tomcat apache server, 
done with java environmental variables setup as below,

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers - **Version: Indigo Service Release 2**
**Apache Tomcat v 7**

**UserVariables:**
**CLASSPATH :** .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\lib;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\lib
**JAVA_HOME :** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0
**JDK_HOME :** %JAVA_HOME%
**JRE_HOME :** C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre

**System variables:**
**Path :** %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Windows\;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem

On starting server, its stops printing the below logs in the console, I am not sure where I am wrong, Please help on this..

```
Jul 09, 2016 11:01:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre8/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\eclipse;;.
Jul 09, 2016 11:01:49 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 09, 2016 11:01:49 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 600 ms
Jul 09, 2016 11:01:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 09, 2016 11:01:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.32
Jul 09, 2016 11:01:49 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Jul 09, 2016 11:01:49 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jul 09, 2016 11:01:49 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/31  config=null
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.Context.addLifecycleListener(Lorg/apache/catalina/LifecycleListener;)V
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.registerContextListener(ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.registerListenersForHost(ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.registerListenersForEngine(ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.registerListenersForServer(ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.lifecycleEvent(ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the tomcat jar files were installed in the $CATALINA_BASE/lib and the CATALINA_HOME was pointing to a different version of tomcat than what was in the $CATALINA_BASE/lib.

Use Tomcat 7.0.21 or above

Answer (score 0):

in order to create new workspace use following steps:
step1:
     open eclipse with new workspace [don't use old workspace]

step2:
     create simple web/project application [at project creation time eclipse ask for jdk and jre point to those which you want to use]

step3:
     add only those jars which needed [this type of problem also occur when 
one jar override class of other in this case you have added GWT jars??]

step4:
   add tomact [rather than installing use stand alone]

step5:
   check all ports are avilable if not change it

*when you made some configuration level changes clean tomcat work directory